# Can PermGen leak out into native heap?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, glassfish, java-6

We are running a Glassfish application with below settings:

```
-XX:PermSize=1g
-XX:MaxPermSize=2g
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1048576
```

JDK version is 6u45

We're observing a memory leak - java process of Glassfish grows constantly - `RES` getting > 15GB (our server has 16GB of physical memory, so admins restart Glassfish before hitting the physical limits), but we never get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

The output of `jmap -permstat` after letting the application run for long time, showing that classloaders are occupying **~9.5GB (!!!)**:

```
class_loader    classes bytes   parent_loader   alive?  type

<bootstrap> 4242    24064120      null      live    <internal>
0x0000000794a4c030  20  274072  0x0000000794a4c098  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x0000000609cdc9f0
...
<many, many Groovy class loaders>
0x000000077f9c80d8  0   0   0x00000007017859f8  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader@0x0000000609997f00
0x000000076d63b3e0  0   0   0x00000007017859f8  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader@0x0000000609997f00
0x000000075a4c5248  20  261784  0x000000075a4c52b0  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@0x0000000609cdc9f0
0x000000078ea2e998  0   0   0x00000007017859f8  dead    groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader@0x0000000609997f00
...
total = 73518   745295  9690318280      N/A     alive=1, dead=73517     N/A
```

At the same time `jmap -heap` shows PermGen using 700MB:

```
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   used     = 823831536 (785.6669769287109MB)
   free     = 1323652112 (1262.333023071289MB)
   38.362645357847214% used
```

I always thought that using `-XX:MaxPermSize` and `-Xmx` you can control how much memory will java process allocate (throwing OOM in case needed more).
I my understanding this process should take roughly up to:

```
4G (heap) + 2G (PermGen) + N*1MB (N thread's stacks) ~= 7.5G (by 500 threads)
```

### The Question

We know that the leak comes from old Groovy version and missing PermGen sweeping flags, but how is that possible that classloaders occupy 9.5GB of memory which does not belong to neither PermGen nor to java heap?

---

### Edit

Just a clarification - the question is not how to solve memory leak issue, it's about ***how come JVM allows such memory allocation***.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much of an answer, but however.
This is tricky. Be aware that JVM's going to use extra wiggle room for `Garbage collection` (especially G1), Metaspace : Permgen in Java8 ( so not applicable in your case),  JIT optimization, and [direct buffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) that may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap.

In either case, analyze heap dump to see what is the application behavior. Generally the bug is with in the application than in JVM. Also you should let the application run in to `OutOfMemory` and see what exact cause is mentioned.

Comment: Regarding direct buffers (we don't user them in our code) I have used `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1048576` to make sure that no big native memory chunks are occupied by third party libs.